# How to access a variable stored in a function in R

Tags: r

One of the features of R that I've been working with lately (thanks `R.cache`) is the ability of functions to declare other functions.  In particular, when one does this, one is able to have some variables be an inherent part of the resulting function.

For example:

```
functionBuilder <- function(wordToSay) {
  function() {
    print(wordToSay)
  }
}
```

Can build a function like so:

`functionToRun <- functionBuilder("hello nested world")`

Then `functionToRun()` will result in `"hello nested world"`.  But if you just look at functionToRun (i.e., print it), you will see code that matches `functionBuilder`.  What you will also see is that `functionToRun` has an environment.  How can one access the value of `wordToSay` that is stored inside of `functionToRun`?

At first I tried:

`get("wordToSay",env=functionToRun)`

... but functionToRun isn't an environment and can't be transformed into an environment via as.environment.  Similarly, because `functionToRun` isn't an environment, you can't attach to it or use `with`.

Answer (score 2):

I found that `environment` was the accessor function to get and set environments, in an analgous way to how `names` gets and sets name attributes.  Therefore, the code to get `functionToRun`'s environment is `environment(functionToRun)` and therefore, we can access `wordToSay` with the line `get("wordToSay",environment(functionToRun))`.