# Accessing the function that is being called from within the function

Tags: r

Within a function, how can we reliably return an object that contains the function itself?

For example with:

```
functionBuilder <- function(wordToSay) {
  function(otherWordToSay) {
    print(wordToSay)
    print(otherWordToSay)
    get(as.character(match.call()[[1]]))
  }
}
```

I can build a function like so:

`functionToRun <- functionBuilder("hello nested world")`

... and run it ...

```
functionToRun("A")
#[1] "hello nested world"
#[1] "A"
#
#function(otherWordToSay) {
#        print(wordToSay)
#        print(otherWordToSay)
#        get(as.character(match.call()[[1]]))
#      }
#<environment: 0x1e313678>
```

... as you can see `functionToRun` returns itself.  However, this approach appears to break if I call functionToRun via `sapply`:

```
> sapply(LETTERS, functionToRun)
#[1] "hello nested world"
#[1] "A"
#Error in get(as.character(match.call()[[1]])) : object 'FUN' not found
```

I can see that this is because the actual call when using sapply is `FUN` but that `FUN` doesn't exist at pos = -1 (the default for get).  Code that works in that position looks like:

`get(as.character(match.call()[[1]]),envir = sys.frame(sys.parent()))`

But that same code fails if the function hasn't been called via `sapply` because `sys.frame(sys.parent()))` goes too far back and ends up referring to `R_GlobalEnv`.

From the documentation (R 3.2.2) I'd have expected `dynGet` to perhaps solve the issue of only going as far back in the stack as needed.  Although this works for an `sapply` call of the function, it fails when the function is called on its own. (Besides, it is marked as 'somewhat experimental').  Inversely `getAnywhere` seems promising, but doesn't seem to work for the `sapply` called function.

Is there a reliable way to return the function that is currently being processed, i.e. works for both a bare and sapply wrapped function call?

What I'm doing right now is wrapping the attempt to grab the function in a tryCatch; but I'm a little uncertain whether I can trust that `get(as.character(match.call()[[1]]),envir = sys.frame(sys.parent()))` will work in all wrapping cases (not just sapply).  So, I'm looking for a more reasonable way to approach this problem.

Potentially Related Questions:

- [How to access a variable stored in a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444887/how-to-access-a-variable-stored-in-a-function-in-r)
- [How to get the name of the calling function inside the called routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595478/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-inside-the-called-routine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this will work in all cases, but it looks okay:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  print(x)
  y <- exp(x)
  print(y)
  sys.function(0)
}

fun(1)
# [1] 1
# [1] 2.718282
# function(x) {
#   print(x)
#   y <- exp(x)
#   print(y)
#   sys.function(0)
# }
lapply(1:5, fun)[[3]]
# [1] 1
# [1] 2.718282
# [1] 2
# [1] 7.389056
# [1] 3
# [1] 20.08554
# [1] 4
# [1] 54.59815
# [1] 5
# [1] 148.4132
# function(x) {
#   print(x)
#   y <- exp(x)
#   print(y)
#   sys.function(0)
# }
```

Of course, I don't understand what you need this for.

Comment: I think it is pretty general purpose, but I'm using this to implement a caching layer similar to `R.cache`.  So, I want to get the function itself so that I can digest it and use that as part of the hash for storing the result of the function to guarantee that the cached result matches what the result the function would currently generate.